# Stable JVM but system memory increase

Tags: java, jvm, orientdb, hazelcast

I am running a java application on a Ubuntu 16.04 server. After extensive investigation I have discovered that the JVM heap size is more or less constant. At any rate there are no memory increase.

However, when I look at the server using `htop` the memory consumption of the server grows at an alarming rate. I am not sure what exactly is causing this but its 100% originating from java process.

I have looked at the `hprof` files but I cant really tell what Im looking for.

I am running two libs that might be responsible but I am not intimately familiar with them;

- *OrientDB (plocal)*
- *Hazelcast*

Im not sure if either / both of these would cause a memory increase outside the JVM.

Any advice on the best plan to help identify the problem would be great.

Comment: Does the RSS of the java process itself increase?

Comment: @the8472 Sorry what is `java process RSS`?

Comment: How are you determining the Java heap size? (Does the method consider only live objects?) How are you determining "memory consumption"?

Comment: It could be well known direct IO leak: http://www.evanjones.ca/java-bytebuffer-leak.html, try to check that. Moreover, Hazelcast (depends on config) could use offheap memory to cache data

Comment: @davmac I'm using *Jprofiler* to asses the memory. Im just in transit so not sure if Im including live objects. I will check shortly and report.

Comment: @qwwdfsad I do implement a plugin architecture using [pf4j](https://github.com/decebals/pf4j) that loads the plugin files dynamically so it could be the IO problem that you mention as it appears NIO API uses caches outside the JVM.

Comment: RSS = resident set size

Comment: @tarka I meant, you should include full details of how you measure both heap size and memory consumption. You say `htop` but what exact measure from `htop`? etc. You need to include these details in your question, don't just reply to the comments - edit your question.

Comment: Hi, we have fixed memory leak on 2.2 rc1 could you try it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Thanks to @the8472, @davmac @qwwdfsad and @andrey-lomakin for your comments. I appreciate the details provided in the question where very thin but I was trying to avoid providing unrelated data that might lead down a rabbit whole.*

I systematically tested each suggestion and it turns out that the problem was originating from **OrientDB**. I cant say 100% which of the following fixed the problem (possibly both). As per @andrey-lomakin suggestion I upgraded from `2.1.19` to `2.2-rc1`. In doing this the applications *batch inserts* started throwing exceptions so I converted them all into single linear queries. Once compete the memory leak has gone.

As a side note in case it affects anybody else while testing for [direct IO leak](http://www.evanjones.ca/java-bytebuffer-leak.html) I did discover to my suprise that `-Djdk.nio.maxCachedBufferSize=...` works with`Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)`.