# OrientDB OByteBufferPool Error

Tags: java, orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I have just upgraded OrientDB from **2.1.19** to **2.2-rc1** as a result of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37077040/stable-jvm-but-system-memory-increase).

As a recap, I'm running OrientDB in embedded `plocal` and the application is being launched with the following settings (only included relevant ones):

```
java -d64 -Xmx2G -Dstorage.diskCache.bufferSize=10000 -server -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:CompileThreshold=200 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=${LOG_PATH}/heapdump.hprof -jar app start
```

The application launches and initially everything works great. However after a little while I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.orientechnologies.common.directmemory.OByteBufferPool.acquireDirect(OByteBufferPool.java:269)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.cache.local.OWOWCache.cacheFileContent(OWOWCache.java:1206)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.cache.local.OWOWCache.load(OWOWCache.java:617)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.cache.local.twoq.O2QCache.updateCache(O2QCache.java:1224)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.cache.local.twoq.O2QCache.doLoad(O2QCache.java:447)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.cache.local.twoq.O2QCache.load(O2QCache.java:392)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.base.ODurableComponent.loadPage(ODurableComponent.java:150)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OPaginatedCluster.readRecordNoLock(OPaginatedCluster.java:649) 
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OPaginatedCluster.readRecord(OPaginatedCluster.java:622)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.doReadRecord(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:3163)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.readRecord(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:2805)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.readRecord(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1023)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx$SimpleRecordReader.readRecord(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:3168)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.executeReadRecord(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:1824)
```

Once the error has occurred **some queries** stop working. I'm guessing the error is originating from a lack of native memory. Does anybody have any insight as to what specifically is causing this and how to prevent it. I can allocate more memory if needed. I'm just not sure the *type* of memory to allocate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's missing this new setting:

```
-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512g
```

Please look at all the changes in v2.2 before to upgrade: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Release-2.2.0.html#release-22x.

Comment: Hi Luca, don't you think 512g is a little bit too much? I run tests with embedded orientdb and maven cannot start forked VM with MaxDirectMemorySize=512g.

Comment: `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512g` is just an upper bound limit and with JVM 64 bit it's never a problem. If you use 32bit JVM try setting it at 2G